# Get element text/value by class name in list of li items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of `li` items and need to get only those that contain the class name `ms-selected`. From the list that i'm iterating through, each `li` shows as this `li#49-selection.ms-elem-selection.ms-selected`. The number isn't always the same and I'm only looking for those `li` values that have `.ms-selected`. How can I accomplish this? I've tried this and different variations so far:

```
var thelist = $("#ms-fmultiselect .ms-selection .ms-list li");

$.each(thelist, function (i, obj) {
    thearray.push({ id: $(".ms-selected").val() });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the jQuery [`.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) function.

```
 var thelist = $("#ms-fmultiselect .ms-selection .ms-list li");

 $.each(thelist, function (i, obj) {
     if($(obj).hasClass('ms-selected')){
         thearray.push($(obj).val());
     }
 });
```

---

Here is a working example with a simplified selector:

```js
var thelist = $('input');
var thearray = [];
$.each(thelist,function(i,obj){
  if($(obj).hasClass('ms-selection')){
         thearray.push($(obj).val());
     }
});

console.log(thearray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="test1">
<input type="text" class="ms-selection" value="test2">
<input type="text" value="test3">
<input type="text" value="test4">
<input type="text" class="ms-selection" value="test5">
<input type="text" value="test6">
<input type="text" class="ms-selection" value="test7">
<input type="text" value="test8">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
var thelist = $("#ms-fmultiselect .ms-selection .ms-list li");
thelist.each(function(idx, li) {
    var item = $(li);
    if(item.hasClass('ms-selected'){
        thearray.push({ id: item.val() });
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem here is not wether he uses `$.each()` or `$elem.each()`, but rather the usage of `hasClass` which is not at all in his original question.

Answer (score 0):

If the only items you want in your list are the ones that have the class "ms-selected", you should be able to simply do

```
var thelist = $("#ms-fmultiselect .ms-selection .ms-list li.ms-selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be much better to iterate on just the required selectors which in your case is "#ms-fmultiselect .ms-selection .ms-list li.ms-selected". this would return you all the filtered li which have the class ms-selected. This way you would not need to iterate over unnecessary elements and filter again.

You could use:

```
    $("#ms-fmultiselect .ms-selection .ms-list li.ms-selected").each(function (){
            thearray.push($(this).val());

    });
```